# Submitting and retrieving data for user profile

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to using firebase and I have a web app that I want to allow users to submit and save their information for their profile in the real-time database. I also want to display some of the information that was submitted on my index and user profile pages. Another issue I am having is that when I log in to the user, it doesn't direct me to the profile page based on the user.

Web App HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!---Required meta tags--->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/editprofile.css">
        <script>"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"</script>
        <!---Required meta tags--->
    
        <!---Like Button JavaScript--->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6dcf461c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!---Like Button JavaScript--->
    
        <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
        
        <title>StudioPick</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item2">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <form class="container py-5 h-100" id="studioForm">
            <div class="container">
                <main>
                  <div class="py-5 text-center">
                    <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="72" height="57">
                    <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
                    <p class="lead">Here is where you can change your profile settings and update your personal information.</p>
                  </div>
              
                  <div class="row g-5">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
                      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                        <span>Your Profile Picure</span>
                      </h4>
                      
                      <div class="profile-img">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" id="profile-pic" src="Images/placeholder.png" alt="">
                      </div>
              
                      <form class="card p-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                      <h4 class="mb-3">Personal Information</h4>
                      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                        <div class="row g-3">
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="John" value="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Valid first name is required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Doe" value="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Valid last name is required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please enter a valid email address for updates.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please enter your address.
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Phone number required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="country" required="">
                              <option value="">Choose...</option>
                              <option>United States</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please select a valid country.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="state" class="form-label">State</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="state" required="">
                              <option value="">Choose...</option>
                              <option>California</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Please provide a valid state.
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              City required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="zip" class="form-label">Zip</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="12345" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Zip code required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="studio" class="form-label">Studio Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studio" placeholder="GOOD Records" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Studio name required.
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <hr class="my-4">
              
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>
              
                        <div class="my-3">
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="paypal" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="paypal">PayPal</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <div class="row gy-3">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="cc-name" class="form-label">Name on card</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" placeholder="" required="">
                            <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Name on card is required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="cc-number" class="form-label">Credit card number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Credit card number is required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="cc-expiration" class="form-label">Expiration</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Expiration date required
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="cc-cvv" class="form-label">CVV</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required="">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              Security code required
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              
                        <hr class="my-4">
              
                        <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()", onclick="submitStu()", window.location.href='editprofile.html'">Update Info</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </main>
              
                <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
                  <p class="mb-1">© 2022 StudioPick.</p>
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </footer>
              </div>
        </form>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <!---Javascript--->
    <script src="Javascript/editprofile.js"></script>
    <!---Javascript--->
    
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
</body>
</html>
```

Firebase javascript:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth()
const database = firebase.database()

var userEntry = firebase.database()
.ref('/Studiopick/studios/users');

var stuEntry = firebase.database()
.ref('/Studiopick/studios/studioId/stuInfo');

document.getElementById('studioForm')
.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

document.getElementById('studioForm')
.addEventListener('submit', submitStu);

//Register A New User
function submitForm() {

    // Get values
    firstName = getInputVal('firstName');
    lastName = getInputVal('lastName');
    email = getInputVal('email');
    phoneNumber = getInputVal('phoneNumber');
    password = getInputVal('password');

    // Submit Profile Info
    saveUser(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, password);
    document.getElementById('studioForm');
}

//Register A New Studio
function submitStu() {

    // Get values
    address = getInputVal('address');
    country = getInputVal('country');
    state = getInputVal('state');
    city = getinputVal('city');
    zip = getInputVal('zip');
    studio = getInputVal('studio');
   

    // Submit Profile Info
    saveStu(address, country, state, city, zip,  studio);
    document.getElementById('studioForm');
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
  
// Save new user to firebase
function saveUser(email, fullName, phoneNumber, userName, password) {
    var newUserEntry = userEntry;
        newUserEntry.push({
            email:email,
            fullName:fullName,
            phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
            userName:userName,
            password:password,
            last_login : Date.now()
    
        });
    }
    
    // Save new/update studio to firebase
    function saveStu(address, country, state, city, zip, studio) {
        var newStuEntry = stuEntry;
            newStuEntry.push({
                address:address,
                country:country,
                state:state,
                city:city,
                zip:zip,
                studio:studio,
        
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Featching the Data in inputs add this function

```
fuserdata(user);

function fuserdata(user){

  var name = user.displayName;
  var email = user.email;
  var phone = user.phoneNumber
  // you can featch more data with refrance to the firebase docs 
  //https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User
  document.getElemetByID('Name').value = name ;
  console.log(name);
  document.getElemetByID('Email').value = email ;
  console.log(email);
  document.getElemetByID('Phone').value = phone ;   
  console.log(phone);

  
      
}
```